# Let $G$ be a finite group of order $d$ and $n$ be an integer with $\gcd(n, d)=1$. Prove the mapping $f:G\to G$, $f(x)=x^n$ is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have trouble with an exercise in group theory.

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $d$ and $n$ be an integer with $\gcd(n, d)=1$. Prove the map $f:G\to G$, $f(x)=x^n$ is bijective.

Since the group may not be abelian,  the mapping may not be a homorphism,  so I can't use notions related to that like kernel.  I don't know how to make use of the order condition.

Is this a classical exercise or theorem?

Any hint is welcome,  thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is of order $d$ then $x^d$ is the identity; if $n$ is coprime with $d$ then $an-bd=1$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: thanks! Mr. editor and shaun! I'm just a new comer/ beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a map between finite sets it is enough to show that it is injective. There exists $u,v$ with $un+vd=1$. Lagrange implies that $x^d=1$ for every $x\in G$, we deduce that $x=x^{un+vd}=(x^n)^u$ thus $x^n=y^n$ implies that $(x^n)^u=(y^n)^u$ and $x=y$ thus $f$ is injective and surjective.

Comment: oh I understand!  so from this trick in fact this map is bijective if and only if $n$ is coprime with $d$

Comment: $x=x^{un+vd}=(x^n)^u=(x^u)^n$ proves that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 3):

It is perhaps fun to note that the converse also holds, namely

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $d$ and $n$ be an integer. If the map $f:G\to G$, $f(x)=x^n$ is bijective, then  $\gcd(n, d)=1$.

Proof: assume that $\gcd(n,d) \neq 1$, say the prime $p$ divides both $n$ and $d$. Cauchy's Theorem asserts the existence of an $x \in G$, with $order(x)=p$, $x \neq e$, the identity element of $G$. However, $f(x)=x^n=(x^p)^{\frac{n}{p}}=e^{\frac{n}{p}}=e$. Since $f$ is injective this would imply $x=e$ a contradiction.