# Fix $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $G$ be a group where $|g|\mid n,\forall g\in G$. If $\gcd(n,m)=1$, prove $f: G \to G,g\to g^m$, is injective, without Lagrange.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Fix a natural number $n$. Let $G$ be a group with the property $|g| \mid n, \forall g \in G$. If $\gcd(n,m)=1$, prove that $f: G \to G$ via $g \to g^m$ is injective, without Lagrange's theorem

I noticed some post like the one below uses Lagrange's Theorem (and some other theorems). But we have not learned those yet.
[Let $G$ be a finite group of order $d$ and $n$ be an integer with $\gcd(n, d)=1$. Prove the mapping $f:G\to G$, $f(x)=x^n$ is bijective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448449/let-g-be-a-finite-group-of-order-d-and-n-be-an-integer-with-gcdn-d-1)

So far, I know two ways to show injectivity:

- Assume $f(x) = f(y)$ and show $x = y$. So this means $x^m = y^m$. Some ideas I had was to somehow use $\gcd(n,m) = 1 \implies an+bm = 1$ for some integer $a,b$. But I had no idea where to go.
- Show $\ker f = \{e\}$, the identity. But I had no idea where to go.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem is so basic. I recommend you to learn it and then try this exercise. Usually yo need some results to work

Comment: You cannot use the kernel unless you know $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @Guillerminho77 IKR! But we will learn Lagrange literally in the next chapter. The prof has stressed about not using theorems we haven't learnt yet.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $\gcd(m,n)=1$, there exist integers $r,s$ such that $rn+sm=1$. Also $x^n=e$ for all $x\in G$.

So suppose that $x^m=y^m$. Then $x^{sm} = (x^m)^s = (y^m)^s = y^{sm}$.

So $x^{1-rn}=x^{sm}=y^{sm}=y^{1-rn}$.

And $x^{1-rn} = x(x^n)^{-r}$...

Can you take it from there?

---

I don't think Lagrange's Theorem is relevant here. Note that $G$ is not assumed to be finite.

Answer (score 3):

The fact is that $g^n=g^{k\cdot{\rm ord}(g)}=(g^{{\rm ord}(g)})^k=1^k=1, \forall g\in G,$ because ${\rm ord}(g)$ divides $n$ so there exist some $k$ such as $n=k\cdot{\rm ord}(g)$.
Also $\gcd(m,n)=1 \implies an+bm=1$, for some integers $a,b$. Now

$$\begin{align}
g^1&=g\\
&=g^{an+bm}\\
&=(g^n)^a(g^m)^b\\
&=(g^m)^b.
\end{align}$$

So

$$\begin{align}
f(g)=f(g')&\iff g^m=g'^m\\
&\iff (g^m)^b=(g'^m)^b \\
&\implies g^{an+bm}=g'^{an+bm} \\
&\implies g=g'.
\end{align}$$