# G finite abelian group, m $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(m, o(G)) = 1$. Prove that for any $y \in G$, we can find $x \in G$ such that $x^m = y$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let G be a finite abelian group, m $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(m, o(G)) = 1$. Prove that for any $y \in G$, we can find $x \in G$ such that $x^m = y$.

My attempt:
Let $|G| = n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have $km + ln = 1$ for $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $y \in G$ has order j, by Lagrange Theorem, $j|n$. Suppose $n=ij$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Claim: $x = y^k$ is the desired x. As G is a group, by closure $x \in G$. 
$x^m = y^{km} = y^{1-ln} = y^1y^{-ln}=y^1y^{-lij}=y(y^{j})^{-li}=ye^{-li}=y$.

My questions:

1. I am still quiet naive to the subject so bare with me...does this looks right/did I omit some details?
2. I very much acknowledged there might be duplicates that discuss similar idea in different form. One thing I was thinking about when constructing the proof was the Euler's theorem (namely, $a^{o(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$) but I could not find out how to use it. Any suggestions?
3. Here G is defined as a finite abelian group. I do not think I explicitly used the abelian property anywhere, while I suspect I omitted some details. Is there any reason why/if we need G to be Abelian here?

Any reply appreciated!

Comment: Where is the $y$ that the exercise asks about? Is that your $g$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes sorry that was a typo - edited

Comment: Minor quibble: You write $kn + lm = 1$ but then you later use $km + ln = 1$. Otherwise it is fine. Yes it works for any group, not just abelian.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks for the catch! Also edited. And thanks for the clarification!

Comment: As remarked above, abelianess is not needed: the map $f: G \rightarrow G$, defined by $f(x)=x^m$ is a bijection (if $G$ is abelian even a homomorphism) for every $m$ relative prime to $|G|$.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448449/let-g-be-a-finite-group-of-order-d-and-n-be-an-integer-with-gcdn-d-1

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @NickyHekster Oh that does make sense & thanks for posting the link! Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Abelianness allows an easy proof $a^m=b^m\implies(ab^{-1})^m=e\implies a=b$ for the injectivity of $x\mapsto x^m$.